# Binary Search for Prefix in C++

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search, prefix

I have a sorted vector of strings in C++.

What I am trying to do is check whether a candidate string is a prefix of one of the strings in the vector. Due to size constraints a linear scan won't work.

How can I implement a custom comparator to do this?

From my understanding, the current comparator on strings will be as follows:

```
class search_comparator {
public:
    bool operator()(const string &value, const string &element) const
    {
          return value < element;
    }
};
```

Now I know from [C++ Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search):

> for all elements, if element < value or comp(element, value) is true
> then !(value < element) or !comp(value, element) is also true

But how can I add the condition to check for substring into this comparator?

One alternative way is to use the lower_bound function and check if the result contains the substring, but I was wondering if it possible with binary_search directly.

My own solution using lower_bound is below (which works faster than linear scan at least on my machine):

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        getline(cin, needle);
        auto found = lower_bound(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), needle);
        if (found != haystack.end() && (*found).rfind(needle, 0) != string::npos) {
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would the vector of strings being sorted help you to find a string containing a particular substring? Consider a sorted vector of numbers. If you’re looking for the number 10, and the number in the middle of the vector is 5, you know that the value (if present) must be in the second half of the list. But if you’re looking for a string with the substring “pqr”, and the middle of the vector has “jkl”, how would you know which side to rule out? There could be “apqr” at the beginning of the list or “zpqr” at the end, after all.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to get better than performance than a linear scan. After all if my vector of strings is something like `{"a", "b", "ba"}` and I'm searching for `"a"`. `"b"` doesn't contain `"a"` as a substring. But both stuff _before_ `"b"` _and_ after `"b"` do!

Comment: *"How can I implement a custom comparator to do this?"* - How is a *comparator* relevant to this? Are you trying to sort your vector based on substrings somehow?

Comment: Binary search won't work, you need to find a different method.

Comment: I used lower_bound which works faster than a linear scan.

Please see my edit for my current solution. By sorting the vector of strings, I can compare strings with my "needle" lexicographically.  By using lower_bound it will return the first string in my vector greater than or equal to my needle. I then check if the found string contains the needle.

Comment: @Sneftel, apologies I should have added "begins with" my candidate string, hopefully the edit is a bit clearer. - I left out this key bit of info by accident while typing.

Comment: In that case you’re looking for “prefix”, not a “substring”. Glad to hear you found a solution; consider posting it as an answer! (You might want to edit the question to say “prefix” so that people with the same issue are more likely to find it.

Comment: Thank you - I was unaware of the terminology.

Comment: Also, a note on the solution — yours fails for the case where you’re looking for, say, "abc” and the vector contains only “zabc”. You want to see whether the lower bound begins with the target, not whether it contains it.

Comment: @Sneftel - thank you I had completely missed that - I will try and see if I can incorporate in my solution below.

Comment: There isn't a total ordering that incorporates the prefix restriction.  `lower_bound` followed by a check is the best way.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this problem is to using `lower_bound` which from my understanding uses the binary_search algorithm on a sorted vector.

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        getline(cin, needle);
        auto found = lower_bound(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), needle);
        if (found != haystack.end() && (*found).rfind(needle, 0) != string::npos) {
            count++;
        }
    }
```

If anyone has a more elegant or quicker solution, please feel free to edit and improve.

I'm using `rfind(needle, 0)` as per @Sneftel's comment to find true prefix.

Answer (score 2):

A while ago I [asked](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/220752/183642) something like this. We can repurpuse the fine answer there:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iterator>
#include <ranges>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

template <std::ranges::range Rng>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr bool pref_exists(Rng const& rng,
                                         std::string_view const pref) noexcept {
  auto const iter = std::ranges::lower_bound(
      rng, pref,
      [n = pref.size()](std::string_view const a,
                        std::string_view const b) noexcept {
        return a.substr(0, n) < b.substr(0, n);
      });

  return iter != std::end(rng) && std::string_view{*iter}.starts_with(pref);
}

int main() {
  std::string words[] = {
      "hello",       "world",   "testing",   "theatergoer", "theatricals",
      "theirselves", "someone", "somewhere", "something",
  };

  std::ranges::sort(words);

  for (auto& pref : {"some", "the", "hal", "aab", "wo"}) {
    std::printf("prefix \"%s\" : does%s exist.\n", pref,
                pref_exists(words, pref) ? "" : "n't");
  }
}
```

Assuming the prefixes and strings are small, this has a complexity of O(log n) where n is the number of strings in the array.